# How to replace selected elements of a list of rules with another unbalanced list of rules

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, code-request

I have two lists of rules:

```
aa = {1 -> {5, 2}, 3 -> {2, 2}, 4 -> {2, 3}, 5 -> {1, 2}, 6 -> {1, 1},
7 -> {2, 1}, 8 -> {1, 1}};
newVnames = {1 -> "EGW", 2 -> "MA2", 3 -> "HLT", 4 -> "AGF", 
5 -> "WHS", 6 -> "TSC", 7 -> "CO12", 8 -> "FIN"};
```

List `aa` has 7 elements, while `newVnames` has 8 (unbalanced lists). This implies that we need first to drop one irrelevant rule from `newVnames` `which is 2->"MA2"` and then replace the remaining elements in `newVnames` in **ONLY** to the `first` elements (before `->`) of `aa`.

For example, `{1->"EGW"}` in `newVnames` should be replaced in the `first` element of the `first` element in `aa` to get:

```
EGW->{5,2}
```

I tried various versions of:

```
Table[aa[[i]][[1]] /. newVnames[[i]], {i, Length[aa]}]
```

But I could not get what I want to. Please advise me a `code` for this task.

Comment: `Normal@KeyMap[Association[newVnames]]@Association[aa]`?

Comment: or `Normal@KeyMap[ReplaceAll[newVnames]]@Association[aa]`?

Comment: or `SubsetMap[ReplaceAll[newVnames], aa, {All, 1}]`

Comment: also `SubsetMap[ReplaceAll@newVnames, {All, 1}]@aa`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Normal @ KeyMap[Association @ newVnames] @ Association @ aa
Normal @ KeyMap[ReplaceAll @ newVnames] @ Association @ aa
MapAt[ReplaceAll @ newVnames, {All, 1}] @ aa 
SubsetMap[ReplaceAll @ newVnames, {All, 1}] @ aa
```

all give

> ```
> {"EGW" -> {5, 2}, "HLT" -> {2, 2}, "AGF" -> {2, 3}, "WHS" -> {1, 2}, 
> "TSC" -> {1, 1}, "CO12" -> {2, 1}, "FIN" -> {1, 1}}
> ```

You can also do in-place replacement using `ReplaceAll[newVnames]` with [`ApplyTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplyTo.html):

```
aa[[All, 1]] //= ReplaceAll[newVnames];
aa
```

> ```
> {"EGW" -> {5, 2}, "HLT" -> {2, 2}, "AGF" -> {2, 3}, "WHS" -> {1, 2}, 
> "TSC" -> {1, 1}, "CO12" -> {2, 1}, "FIN" -> {1, 1}}
> ```

Answer (score 12):

```
Replace[aa, newVnames,2]

(* {EGW -> {5, 2}, HLT -> {2, 2}, AGF -> {2, 3}, WHS -> {1, 2}, TSC -> {1, 1}, 
    CO12 -> {2, 1}, FIN -> {1, 1}} *)
```

Comment: Well now I feel stupid. Very nice.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe the following can help:

```
 If[Length[#] != 2, Nothing, #[[2, 2]] -> #[[1, 2]]] & /@ 
 GatherBy[Join[aa, newVnames], Keys]
 (*{"EGW" -> {5, 2}, "HLT" -> {2, 2}, "AGF" -> {2, 3}, "WHS" -> {1, 2}, 
    "TSC" -> {1, 1}, "CO12" -> {2, 1}, "FIN" -> {1, 1}}*)
```

Answer (score 9):

I particlarly like @kglr's answers in the comments, but I went down the Merge path:

```
Values[Merge[KeyIntersection[{newVnames, aa}], Apply[Rule]]]
```

Answer (score 9):

**Using `Lookup`:**

```
Thread[Values@newVnames -> 
   Lookup[aa, Keys@newVnames]] // DeleteMissing
```

OR

```
MapThread[Rule, 
 Lookup[KeyIntersection[{newVnames, aa}], #, Nothing] &@
  Keys@newVnames]
```

---

Result:

> {"EGW" -> {5, 2}, "HLT" -> {2, 2}, "AGF" -> {2, 3}, "WHS" -> {1, 2},
> "TSC" -> {1, 1}, "CO12" -> {2, 1}, "FIN" -> {1, 1}}